# Pandas Merge a Grouped-by dataframe with another dataframe for each group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a datframe like:

```
id  date        temperature

1   2011-09-12   12
    2011-09-15   12
    2011-10-13   12
2   2011-12-12   14
    2011-12-24   15
```

I want to make sure that each device id has temperature recordings for each day, if the value exists it will be copied from above if it doesn't i will put 0.

so, I prepare another dataframe which has dates for the entire year:

using `pd.DataFrame(0, index=pd.range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-12'), columns=['temperature'])`

```
date        temperature

2011-01-01     0
.
.
.
2011-12-12    0
```

Now, for each id I want to merge this dataframe so that I have entire year's entry for each of the id.

I am stuck at the merge step, just merging on the date column does not work, i.e.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['date'])
```

gives a blank dataframe.

Comment: can you please write some code to build df1 and df2, so that we can play with data?

Comment: @luca.vercelli edited question to include df2 code

Comment: when you say 'for each id' you mean that you want to have a different (merged) dataframe for each id? or you want a unique dataframe with all ids multiplied by all days of the year?

Comment: @luca.vercelli a single daaframe with each id having all days the second option you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and merge by both `MultiIndex`es:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], 
                                  pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-12')],
                                  names=['id','date'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=mux, columns=['temperature'])

df = pd.merge(df1, df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

If want only one column `temperature`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
df['temperature'] = df.pop('temperature_').fillna(df['temperature'])
```

Another idea is use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for `2 columns` DataFrame:

```
from  itertools import product
data = list(product(df.index.levels[0],  pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-12')))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','date'])
df = pd.merge(df1, df, left_on=['id','date'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

---

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], 
                                  pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-12')],
                                  names=['id','date'])

df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: @tstseby - yes, reason is `df1 = pd.DataFrame(0, index=mux, columns=['temperature'])` - there ai also specifiec column `temperature`. so added another 2 solutions for working with it.

Comment: @tstseby - Add solution to answer for create one column.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55724136/565489), you could also do the following iteration, especially if you want to keep your device id intact:

```
data={"date":[pd.Timestamp('2011-09-12'), pd.Timestamp('2011-09-15'), pd.Timestamp('2011-10-13'),pd.Timestamp('2011-12-12'),pd.Timestamp('2011-12-24')],"temperature":[12,12,12,14,15],"sensor_id":[1,1,1,2,2]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data,index=data["sensor_id"])

df2=pd.DataFrame(0, index=pd.date_range('2011-01-01', '2011-12-12'), columns=['temperature','sensor_id'])

for i,row in df1.iterrows():
    df2.loc[df2.index==row["date"], ['temperature']] = row['temperature']
    df2.loc[df2.index==row["date"], ['sensor_id']] = row['sensor_id']

for t in data["date"]:
    print(df2[df2.index==t])
```

*Note that `df2` in your question only goes to `2011-12-12`, hence the last `print()` will return an empty DataFrame. I wasn't whether you did this on purpose.*

Also, depending on the variability and density in your actual data, it might make sense to use:

```
for s in [1,2]: ## iterate over device ids
    ma=(df['sensor_id']==s)
    df.loc[ma]=df.loc[ma].fillna(method='ffill') # fill forward
```

hence an incomplete time series would be filled (forward) by the last measured temperature value. Depends on the quality of your data, of course, and `df.resample()` might make more sense.